# Generating Rows Based on Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my tables in my database contains rows with requisition numbers and other related info. I am trying to create a second table (populated with an `INSERT INTO` statement) that duplicates these rows and adds a series value based on the value in the `QuantityOrdered` column.

For example, the first table is shown below:

```
+-------------+----------+
| Requisition | Quantity |
+-------------+----------+
| 10001_01_AD |    4     |
+-------------+----------+
```

and I would like the output to be as follows:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+
| Requisition | Quantity |  Series  |
+-------------+----------+----------+
| 10001_01_AD |     4    |     1    |
| 10001_01_AD |     4    |     2    |
| 10001_01_AD |     4    |     3    |
| 10001_01_AD |     4    |     4    |
+-------------+----------+----------+
```

I've been attempting to use `Row_Number()` to sequence the values but it's numbering rows based on instances of Requisition values, not based on the Quantity value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-recursive way:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT n
             FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS n
                   FROM master..spt_values s1) AS sub
             WHERE  sub.n <= t.Quantity) AS s2(Series);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=414d24c33905d4d33bad814e54bb52b8)**

Answer (score 6):

You need recursive way :

```
with t as (
     select Requisition, 1 as start, Quantity
     from table
     union all
     select Requisition, start + 1, Quantity
     from t
     where start < Quantity
 ) 
select Requisition, Quantity, start as Series  
from t;
```

However, by default it has limited to only 100 `Quantities`, if you have a more then you need to specify the query hint by using `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select requsition, quantity, 1 as series
      from t
      union all
      select requsition, quantity, 1 + series
      from t
      where lev < quantity
    )
select requsition, quantity, series
from cte;
```

With default setting, this works up to a quantity of 100.  For larger quantities, you can add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query.