# Generate rows within table based on existing rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to generate rows within a table based on existing column in the table in SQL Server? For example, if `RunDates` value = `31/01/2020` and `RunTimes = 3`, then there should be 3 rows in the table for `RunDate = 31/01/2020`

Current table

[image: Current Table]

Desired table

[image: Desired table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select RunDates, RunTimes, 1 nr from tablename
  union all
  select RunDates, RunTimes, nr + 1 
  from cte
  where nr < RunTimes
)
select RunDates, RunTimes from cte
order by RunDates
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=27c456bf0bf6c36a95484ac01fc59eca).
Results:

```
> RunDates   | RunTimes
> :--------- | -------:
> 2020-01-31 |        3
> 2020-01-31 |        3
> 2020-01-31 |        3
> 2020-02-29 |        2
> 2020-02-29 |        2
> 2020-03-31 |        1
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need a tally table (view) e.g.

```
CREATE View [dbo].[cteTally]
as
WITH
  E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n))
  , E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b) --10E+2 or 100 rows
  , E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b) --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
  , cteTally(N) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
  )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Then you join it on to your table e.g.

```
declare @MyTable table (MyDate date, RunCount int);

insert into @MyTable (MyDate, RunCount)
  values
  ('31 Jan 2020', 3),
  ('29 Feb 2020', 2),
  ('31 Mar 2020', 1);

select MT.*
from @MyTable MT
inner join cteTally T on T.N <= MT.RunCount
order by MyDate, RunCount;
```

Returns:

```
MyDate      RunCount
--------------------
2020-01-31  3
2020-01-31  3
2020-01-31  3
2020-02-29  2
2020-02-29  2
2020-03-31  1
```

NOTE: The Tally Table is courtesy of @Larnu but I can't find the original post.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following inner join by creating a serial number from `sys.objects`.

Here I have fixed `10` assuming the maximum value of `RunTime`. You can create a variable and assign the `maximum` value of the `RunTime` value and use that variable in place of `10`.

Here is an [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52744261/10532500) to do that.

```
create table SampleTable (DtDate Date, RunTimes int)
insert into SampleTable Values
('31 Jan 2020', 3),
('29 Feb 2020', 2),
('31 Mar 2020', 1)

SELECT SampleTable.*
FROM SampleTable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY object_id
            ) AS SrNo
    FROM sys.objects
    ) mst ON RunTimes >= SrNo
ORDER BY DtDate
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31a3601b064e22847ee531a9d9834930) demo.