# Extract 7 days of the week as a date from a combination of the year and week number?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (SQL Server 2017) where the data is stored at the level of the year number and week number.

```
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+
    | year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | qty |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+
    | 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 7   |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+
```

I need to get a similar table, but at the day level, where the quantity (**qty**) will be divided into 7 parts evenly for each day.

```
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | qty | date_id    |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-14 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-15 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-16 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-17 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-18 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-19 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
| 2019    | 42          | 113466  | 41       | 1   | 2019-10-20 |
+---------+-------------+---------+----------+-----+------------+
```

I found a way to [get a date from the year and week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474236/construct-date-from-year-and-week-number-in-mssql), but how do I get 7 rows from one at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Rows Based on Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744203/generating-rows-based-on-column-value)

Comment: Date-related problems become a *lot* easier if you create a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). With a Calendar table, all you'd have to do would be join with it on the Year, WeekNumber columns to get one row per day

Comment: How are weeks defined in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a calendar table as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/10532500)
and join the original table as shown below to get the desired output.

```
Select 
      CalendarDate
      , year_id
      , week_number
      , good_id
      , store_id
      , 1 as qty
from dbo.RunningNumbers
inner join ToBeGenerated on CalendarYear = year_id and week_number = CalendarWeek
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f84ce33997a36c552bf5fac45cad1b86) demo.

Comment: Downvoter, why did you downvote the **correct** answer? This is used in **all** reporting databases and star schemas for a reason

Answer (score 1):

There you go. You need to join a table with all the dates and then divide the qty by the value you want:

```sql
use tempdb

CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
   year_id INT, week_number INT, good_id INT, store_id INT, qty INT
)

INSERT INTO tbl1
VALUES (2019, 42, 113466, 41, 7)
GO
WITH sample AS(
   SELECT CAST('2019-10-01' AS DATE) as DT
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(dd,1,dt)
    FROM sample
   WHERE DATEADD(dd,1,dt) < CAST('2019-12-31' AS DATE))

SELECT dt, YEAR(dt) AS [Year], DATEPART(WEEK,dt) AS Week
INTO wks
FROM sample

SELECT t.year_id, t.week_number, t.good_id, t.store_id, qty/7 AS [Qty], dt AS [Date]
  FROM tbl1 t
 INNER JOIN wks S on s.Week = t.week_number
```

Comment: Even better - don't generate the dates, use a Calendar table instead. The CTE generates such a table at runtime without taking advantage of any indexes, which makes this very slow

Comment: We are talking max 100 rows with the recursion limit. So performance will not be an issue.

Comment: It is, if you use that for concurrent calls or event modest number of target rows. Without the indexes, you have to scan the entire target table. That's why Calendar tables are used everywhere, with CTEs only used to generate the date data.  Why not create a properly indexed table and reuse it?

Comment: Why overanalyze this? Question is Answered.

Comment: No it's not. There's a good, performant way to do something and a bad one. In databases, performance matters so this answer is *not* a good one. In fact, the question has been asked 100s of times already with multiple good answers that all boil down to "Use a Calendar Table"

Comment: Not sure if you checked my code that actually uses the CTE to create a calendar table.

Comment: I did, and I was going to comment "why not create a proper permanent Calendar table?"

Comment: @Rabbit . . . I don't think this calculates the dates correctly -- or at least, it hardcodes them in a non-generalizable way.