# Insert N Rows based on select value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically, I have a table `T` with the following information

```
Col1 | Col2 | Factor
A      B      50
C      D      60
```

I now need to insert into `T` n rows duplicates of each row based on the `Factor`. In the first row I would have the following:

`B | string | 1` (50x)
(Where `string` is a hardcoded string)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way uses recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select col1, col2, factor, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select col1, col2, factor - 1, lev + 1
      from cte
      where factor > 1
     )
select col1, col2, 1 as factor  -- or perhaps lev if you want an incrementing value
from cte;
```

Two notes:

- You can use this for an `insert` or `select into`.
- If `factor` can be more than 100, then add `option (maxrecursion 0)` to the query.

Recursive CTEs have surprisingly decent performance.  But if you need to generate zillions of rows, then some sort of number/tally table would be useful.  For instance, if your base table had enough rows:

```
select col1, col2, 1 as factor
from t join
     (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from t
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.factor
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another option as in [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52744261/10532500):

```
Create table FactorTable (Col1 char(1)
 , Col2 char(1)
 , Factor int)

Insert into FactorTable Values
('A', 'B', 50),
('C', 'D', 60)

SELECT *
FROM FactorTable t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT n
             FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0) AS n
                   FROM master..spt_values s1) AS sub
             WHERE  sub.n <= t.Factor) AS s2(Series);
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=460e97e7ac79c74d016cc13d33fa397e) demo.